# Keeping two arrays in the same ordering when sorting

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort

I have an integer array that I need to sort containing unix times. I was going to use qsort to sort it which is fairly trivial. However I also have an array of "strings" that needs to remain in the same order as the integer array.

So position 2 in the integer array would correspond with an element in position two of the other array.

Is there anyway using qsort to maintain such a relationship?

Comment: Use a `struct`, that way you can bind data and sort by the struct member you wish.

Comment: Use indirection. Create an array of indices, 0, 1, ..., N-1 and sort those.

Comment: @iharob how would I accomplish this?

Comment: @fogest are you asking what a struct is?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so the comparrison would be with the integer array data, but it would be sorting the indices array? Because from my understanding I could not do this with qsort as the the data it is using is from the array to be sorted. Unless I'm understanding this differently...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no sorry, I am asking more specifically how I could accomplish this kind of binding he is referring to with the sorting. I am assuming he is meaning I can create an array of structures, and these structures contain the int and string?

Comment: qsort is limited, but if that's your only option, and you can't contemplate a more flexible sort function, then perhaps you can't solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan looks like iharob's solution is what I am looking for! Can't believe I did not think to use a structure in this way! Still have much to learn in C before I start thinking this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Data
{
    long int time;
    const char *string;
};

int
datacmp(const void *const x, const void *const y)
{
    return ((struct Data *) x)->time - ((struct Data *) y)->time;
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct Data array[] = {
        {1234, "1234 Text"},
        {1034, "1034 Text"},
        {1041, "1041 Text"}
    };
    size_t count;

    count = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Entry %zu:\n\ttime  : %ld\n\tstring: %s\n\n", 
            i, array[i].time, array[i].string);
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    qsort(array, count, sizeof(array[0]), datacmp);
    fprintf(stderr, "---- Sorted array:\n");

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < count ; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Entry %zu:\n\ttime  : %ld\n\tstring: %s\n\n", 
            i, array[i].time, array[i].string);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic solution that actually sorts 2 (or more) arrays, according to one of the arrays, by sorting an array of pointers to the key array, then reordering all of the arrays to sort them (it also restores the array of pointers back to their initial state). The compare function only needs to know the type that the pointers point to. The reorder in place takes O(n) (linear) time as every move places a value in it's final sorted location. In this example, a[] is an array of integers, b[] is an array of pointers to strings (char *).

```
int compare(const void *pp0, const void *pp1)
{
    int i0 = **(int **)pp0;
    int i1 = **(int **)pp1;
    if(i0 > i1)return -1;
    if(i0 < i1)return  1;
    return 0;
}
/* ... */

    int *pa = malloc(...);   /* array of pointers */
    int ta;    /* temp value for a */
    char *tb;  /* temp value for b */
    /* ... */

    /* initialize array of pointers to a[] */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        pa[i] = &a[i];
    /* sort array of pointers */
    qsort(pa, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(pa[0]), compare);
    /* reorder a[] and b[] according to the array of pointers */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
        if(i != pa[i]-a){
            ta = a[i];
            tb = b[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = pa[k]-a)){
                a[k] = a[j];
                b[k] = b[j];
                pa[k] = &a[k];
                k = j;
            }
            a[k] = ta;
            b[k] = tb;
            pa[k] = &a[k];
        }
    }
```